# C# Blazor : how to pass a parameter string into MainLayout page

Tags: parameters, blazor

I try to create my first .MAUI hybrid apps. i'd like the pass a string in the MainLayout page when I select a name.
I'm a little lost with parameter, cascade parameter and event Callback. I don't know which is the most appropriate..

my Mainlayout code :

```
<MudText> Centre : @NameSelected</MudText>
@code {
public string NameSelected { get; set; }
}
```

and in my ChildPage :

```
<MudGrid Class="my-5" Spacing="2">
         
                @foreach (var name in user.listName)
                {
                string id = center.Id.ToString();
                <MudItem xs="6" sm="6" md="3">
                    <MudCard  Elevation="1" Class="mr-2 rounded-lg pa-0" @onclick="@(() => SendName(name.Name))">
                        <MudCardContent Class="d-flex flex-column mb-1 mt-1">
                            <MudIcon Color="Color.Info" Class="ma-2 align-self-center" Icon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.LocationOn"
                                       Style="height:60px; width:60px;"> </MudIcon>
                            <MudText Color="Color.Info" Typo="Typo.body1" Align="Align.Center">@center.Name</MudText>
                            <MudText Color="Color.Tertiary" Typo="Typo.caption" Align="Align.Center">Voir les lots</MudText>
                        </MudCardContent>
                    </MudCard>
                </MudItem>
                }
         
        </MudGrid>`@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationState { get; set; }
[Parameter]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
[Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> SendName { get; set; }

private void GoToName(string Name)
    {
        SendName.InvokeAsync(Name);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

but when I click on the link in my child page, nothing appear in the mainlayout.
What is wrong ? what's missing ?

Thanks a lot for your help.